# Find a sum of all positive matrix elements that located before of the largest positive element

Tags: c++

here is what i tried before:

```
//finding maximum
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i][j];
                imax = i;
                jmax = j;
            }
        }
    }
//finding a sum
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] > 0)
            {
                if (i <= imax && j < jmax)
                    sum += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;
}
```

but that algorithm doesn't count it right, how should i do to make it work?
looks like that my code is "limitng" the range of search, because of wrong condition and i duuno how to make it right?

Comment: what means "located before" ? That seems to be the issue in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think step by step.

Assuming, `imax` is the row number and `jmax` is the column number of the maximum elements present in the matrix.

**Row selection procedure:**

So, to accomplish our object, we will traverse `row` which is `<= imax`. That means, we'll consider the value of the current row as our answer only if `current row <= imax`. If the current row becomes larger than `row`, then we can stop traversing .

```
//finding a sum
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] > 0)
        {
            if(i <= imax)
            {
                // do something
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can also do it in below way:

```
//finding a sum
for (int i = 0; i < n && i <= imax; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] > 0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Column selection procedure:**

It's a little bit different from the row selection procedure.

We can consider every column unless current row is equal to `imax`. That means when
`current row < imax` we will consider values of every column, but when `current row == imax` we'll only consider smaller column's value as our answer.

```
//finding a sum
for (int i = 0; i < n && i <= imax; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if(i < imax && arr[i][j] > 0)
        {
            // consider the value for answer
        }
        else
        {
            // here i == imax
            // so we'll only consider smaller column's value as our answer
            if(j < jmax && arr[i][j] > 0)
            {
                // consider the value for answer
            }
            else if(j >= jmax)  // we've come out of the boundary. No matter the value is positive or negative, we don't need to check any further
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Overall code of finding sum portion will look like this:

```
//finding a sum
for (int i = 0; i < n && i <= imax; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if(i < imax && arr[i][j] > 0)
        {
            // consider the value for answer
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
        else
        {
            // here i == imax
            // so we'll only consider smaller column's value as our answer
            if(j < jmax && arr[i][j] > 0)
            {
                // consider the value for answer
                sum += arr[i][j];
            }
            else if(j >= jmax)  // we've come out of the boundary. No matter the value is positive or negative, we don't need to check any further
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Don't forget to initialize the value of `max` , `imax`, `jmax` and `sum` properly.

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't work the way you've set it up.

Suppose you have a matrix like this:

```
0  1  5  10 8
4  22 8  18 11
1  2  6  14 9
1  27 6  14 9
1  2  6  14 9
```

Your max would find that imax = 3, jmax = 1

What happens when you try to count the element at [0, 5]? You miss it because jmax = 1, means all elements to the right of the j =1 column aren't counter by your conditions.

Comment: so, how should i rewrite code to include all incorrectly discarded elements?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean with "located before", but I am almost certain that this is the issue in your code. Supposed the max element is `x` then you add all elements marked with `o` and exclude elements marked with `.`:

```
ooo...
ooo...
oox...
......
......
```

But I'd rather expect either this

```
oooooo
oooooo
oox...
......
......
```

or this:

```
ooo...
ooo...
oox...
oo....
oo....
```